# Does improper integral exists or not?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

The following question is from my real analysis quiz. I was unable to solve it in exam and unfortunately now failed to solve it again at my home.

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \log(\cos^2x) dx $$

I am not able to find out how I would be able to do it. In my opinion, problem is both at $\infty$ and at 0. Finding the limit of integral at 0 and at $\infty$ doesn't seem to be an options as I think it would be really hard to compute the integral. Also, If I break the limit and apply the practical comparison test then in both at 0 and at $\infty$ I am getting the limit as 0.

So, please help me.

Comment: The actual problem is the singularities at $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

From the convexity of $x\mapsto \lvert\cos x\rvert$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and on $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$ respectively, we easily find that

$$ \left| \frac{2x}{\pi} - 1 \right| \leq \left| \cos x \right| \leq 1 \quad \text{for } x \in [0, \pi]. $$

The plot below demonstrates this comparison:

[image: comparison of the functions]

So by taking logarithm to both sides and multiplying by $-2$, we get

$$ 0 \leq -\log(\cos^2 x) \leq -2\log \left| \frac{2x}{\pi} - 1 \right|. $$

In particular, we know that $\log(\cos^2 x)$ is always non-positive. Then by substituting $u = \frac{2x}{\pi} - 1$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \left| \log(\cos^2 x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} \left( - \log (\cos^2 x) \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} (-2)\log \left| \frac{2x}{\pi} - 1 \right|  \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\pi \int_{-1}^{1} \log \left|u\right|  \, \mathrm{d}u \\
&= 2\pi.
\end{align*}

This shows that $\log(\cos^2 x)$ is integrable on $[0, \pi]$ by the comparison test. Finally, using the fact that $e^{-x} \leq e^{-n\pi}$ for each $n \geq 0$ and $x \in [n\pi, (n+1)\pi]$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \left| e^{-x} \log(\cos^2 x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x 
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} e^{-x} \left| \log(\cos^2 x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} e^{-n\pi} \left| \log(\cos^2 x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{1 - e^{-\pi}} \int_{0}^{\pi} \left| \log(\cos^2 x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&< \infty,
\end{align*}

and therefore the improper integral converges.

---

In general logarithmic singularity does not pose any issue for local integrability. In OP's case, the singularities of the integrand $e^{-x}\log(\cos^2 x)$ at $x = n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $ n \in \mathbb{Z}$ are "benign", and so, only the singularity at $x=\infty$ matters.

Comment: What is meant by "OP"?

Comment: @Avenger, This is short for [*original poster*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424366/does-op-mean-original-poster-or-original-post).

Comment: Can you please tell how did you proved that $\left| \frac{2x}{\pi} - 1 \right| \leq \left| \cos x \right| \leq 1$ for $x\in [0,2\pi]$?

Comment: Also , You haven't given any reason on how you deduced the equation that :$\int_{0}^{\pi} \left| \log(\cos^2 x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x
\leq - 2 \int_{0}^{\pi} \log \left| \frac{2x}{\pi} - 1 \right|  \, \mathrm{d}x
$.

Comment: $\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \left| e^{-x} \log(\cos^2 x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x 
&\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} e^{-n\pi} \left| \log(\cos^2 x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{1 - e^{-\pi}} \int_{0}^{\pi} \left| \log(\cos^2 x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&< \infty,
\end{align*}$ In this equation in the middle term (of the three terms) how did you wrote $e^{- n\pi}$ instead of $e^{-x}$ and why is there an inequality instead of equality if we see at first 2 terms.

Comment: @Avenger I added some more details. I believe that what has been left out can be replicated by the reader easily.